# Vue 3: toggle render of 2 components based on one element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

For a project in Vue3 I am working on, I am building an application that that starts with a blank card and a spinner. When a user presses the spinner, after a short delay, the blank card is replaced with an image. I am new to Vue, and JavaScript frameworks for that matter, but I figured the best way to build this in Vue is to toggle between the rendering of two elements. This is part of my code:

```
<div class="guessingImage w-100 col-lg-9 col-sm-12 align-items-center">
        <img
          v-if="userImg"
          :class="{'userImage': userImg }"
          :src="image.url"
          alt=""
        />
        <div v-else class="innerGuessingImage">
          <p>?</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="gameControls col-lg-3 col-sm-12 ">
        <img :src="require('@/assets/images/spin-me-text.png')" alt="" />
        <div
          class="wheel mb-sm-1 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
          @click="changeImage()"
          :class="{'rotate': isOpen}"
        >
          <img
            @click="changeView()"
            :src="require(`@/assets/images/spinner.png`)"
            class="spinner"
            alt=""
          />
        </div>
```

And here

```
data() {
    return {
      isOpen: false,
      userImg: false,
      image: {
        title: String,
        clue: String,
        url: String
      } 
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeImage() {
      this.isOpen = !this.isOpen
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.userImg = !this.userImg
      }, 4000);
    },
    changeView() {
      this.userImg = false;
    }
  },
```

I'm not able to get the two elements to smoothly transition. The second element with the `v-else` attribute is the blank card that should show every time the image/"button" with the `spinner` class is clicked, and the first `v-if` div should show every time the `spinner` class is clicked after a four second delay (this works the first time, but every time after that, I run into issues) What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your data object intended to be pseudo-code for demonstration purposes? Otherwise, your image object looks like props, not data. `image.url` points to a type in your code and not an actual location. Importing assets with `require` in the template is a bit unusual. Unless you have good reason, your should import these in your script and  return them in your data object.

Comment: @Tim `require` is used when you want to import a dynamic image tbh.

Comment: If you want a smooth transition, you should give a look to [`transition`](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition.html#transition) IMO.

Comment: I am using it because I am importing a dynamic image.

Comment: Nothing is dynamic here, your path could have been hardcoded.

Comment: @kissu completely agree with you. Based on the code presented, it did not seem like this was a case for dynamic import. Still unclear if image object should be props?

Comment: The image is being requested by axios from a .json file in the /public folder, for now. The end goal of the application is to allow users to upload a photo and that will be requested somewhere else, so the URL will vary. Should I be using props instead?